# Returning a method without executing it

Tags: php

I have a method that takes a method name in parameter and the return that method (from another class). I don't find out how to return this method without executing it.

Here some code example with a class #1:

```
public function hello() {
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

The method from a class #2:

```
public function getPackageMethod($method) {
    if (method_exists($this->package, $method)) {
        return $this->package->$method; // This seems to return nothing
    }
}
```

And I'd like to get in another script something like this:

```
$obj = new Obj();
$hello = $obj->getPackageMethod('hello');
$hello(); // Calling the method here. But currently got a error that $hello is not a function
```

I think it is possible to do that, but I think I forgot something.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a closure, and then bind an instance of your class #1 to the closure:

```
class salutations {
    public function hello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}

class methodFactory {
    public function __construct($instance) {
        $this->package = $instance;
    }

    public function getPackageMethod($method) {
        if (method_exists($this->package, $method)) {
            $f = function() use ($method) { return $this->package->{$method}(); };
            $f->bindTo($this);
            return $f;
        }
    }
}

$salutationsInstance = new salutations();

$obj = new methodFactory($salutationsInstance);
$hello = $obj->getPackageMethod('hello');
echo $hello();
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/q92nH)

Answer (score 0):

When you return `$this->package->$method`, you already are running it like a attribute. What you need to do is save the method and only run it when you want.

It would be like that:

```
private $method = null;

public function setPackageMethod($method)
{
    $this->method = $method;
}

public function runMethod()
{
    return $this->package->{$this->method}();
}
```

And you can use doing this:

```
$obj->setPackageMethod('hello');
echo $obj->runMethod(); // The method only will be run now
```